# Exception 0x00000004 (sfml-graphics-2.dll) occuring after compilation

Tags: c++, exception, sfml

Recently, I've started to learn SFML. The first thing I wanted to do was a simple menu - so I've created an interface for all menus, containing everything necessary for other menus in protected field. However, my code throws an exception at some point, and I have no idea, why.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Menu
{
protected:
    sf::Color red;
    sf::Color white;
    std::vector<sf::Text> displayedText;
    int currentOption{ 0 };
public:
    virtual void draww(sf::RenderWindow& window) = 0;
    virtual void clickButton() = 0;
    virtual void moveUp() = 0;
    virtual void moveDown() = 0;
};

class FirstMenu : public Menu
{
public:
    FirstMenu(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    {
        sf::Text text;
        sf::Font font;
        if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
        {
            std::cout << "Font error. \n";
        }
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setString("Play");
        displayedText.push_back(text);
        text.setString("Options");
        displayedText.push_back(text);
        displayedText[0].setFillColor(red);
        displayedText[0].setPosition(20, 30);
        displayedText[1].setPosition(30, 30);
    }
    virtual void clickButton()
    {
        switch (currentOption)
        {
        case 0:
            std::cout << "Playing. \n";
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Options. \n";
            break;
        }
    }
    virtual void moveUp()
    {
        currentOption++;
        displayedText[currentOption].setFillColor(white);
        for (int i = 0; i < displayedText.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i == currentOption)
            {
                displayedText[i].setFillColor(red);
            }
        }
    }
    virtual void moveDown()
    {
        currentOption--;
        displayedText[currentOption].setFillColor(white);
        for (int i = 0; i < displayedText.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i == currentOption)
            {
                displayedText[i].setFillColor(red);
            }
        }
    }
    virtual void draww(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    {
        if (!displayedText.empty())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < displayedText.size(); i++)
            {
                window.draw(displayedText[i]); //Exception thrown here
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "SFML works!");
    FirstMenu menu(window);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        menu.draww(window);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Text displayed while throwing exception is:
"Unhandled exception in location 0x799B35BB (sfml-graphics-2.dll)
0xC0000005: Access violation while reading location 0x00000004"

Comment: That error means you are accessing an array out of bounds. Can you debug your program? I've seen a few things I would double check though: 1) I would break out of the while loops after the `window.close()`, 2) I woudl use two `sf::Text` variables at the `FirstMenu` constructor, and 3) I would check `currentOption` to not go out of the `displayedText` vector boundaries (i.e. ++ can't go up `size()-1` and -- can't go down 0.

Comment: Exception still thrown  after trying `auto` with vector. Exception is thrown during debugging.

Comment: How are you building your executable and linking sfml DLL?

Comment: I'm using "Debug x86" option in Visual Studio to debug my code. I'm linking all libraries into "Release" and "Debug" (in Debug, i'm adding "-d" suffix). I completely don't know why my program throws this exception

Comment: Was my code written properly? I don't know if I am making a mistake or if there's a problem with linking SFML into Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue I can see is that in the constructor of `FirstMenu` you are

```
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
{
    std::cout << "Font error. \n";
}
text.setFont(font)
```

Essentially setting the text's font to a local font object. This is problematic because text in SFML doesn't copy the passed in font resource.

SFML's documentation on the text class states this about `setFont`

> The font argument refers to a font that must exist as long as the text
> uses it. Indeed, the text doesn't store its own copy of the font, but
> rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function. If
> the font is destroyed and the text tries to use it, the behavior is
> undefined.

It is also worth noting that the `setTexture` function for Shapes and Sprites behaves similarly as it doesn't store a copy of the texture resource.

The fix is to ensure that the font object is never destroyed while it is being used by a text object.

The simplest fixes include:

1. Load the font in main and pass the font around to functions and objects that need it.
2. If you are using a single font then have a global function that has a static font and constructs and loads it only once.
3. If multiple fonts are needed and you don't want to pass the font around then you could have a singleton resource manager for fonts.